# Update or Select into ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the following statement;

```
SELECT RESV_ID, BOOKING_CUS_ID, ACC_ID,
    (SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID) AS DEPART_FLIGHT_PRICE, 
    (SELECT F1.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F1 WHERE F1.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID) AS RETURN_FLIGHT_PRICE, 
    (SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID) AS ACCOMMODATION_PRICE
    FROM HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R;
```

to yield the following results;

```
   RESV_ID BOOKING_CUS_ID     ACC_ID DEPART_FLIGHT_PRICE RETURN_FLIGHT_PRICE ACCOMMODATION_PRICE
---------- -------------- ---------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
         1              1          2                 520                 450                 350
         2              3          4                 250                 150                 150
         3              5          6                 290                 300                 450
         4              7          7                 399                 450                 650
         5              9                            365                 345
         6             11                            558                 460
         7             13                            250                 250
         8             15                            550                 550
         9             17         25                                                         250
        10             19         19                                                         450

10 rows selected.
```

**Question:**
How do I sum up the price fields, **SOME PRICES ARE NOT AVAILABLE** because a reservation was either made for accommodation only or flight only, hence both values will not be present always and this is where the issue lies

```
DEPART_FLIGHT_PRICE RETURN_FLIGHT_PRICE ACCOMMODATION_PRICE
```

*Furthermore:*
I wish to insert or update the SUM of those three values into a SUBTOTAL in the reservation table, perhaps by using select into or update, I have spent a whole day trying to do this but my skills are limited. any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Flight table**

```
FLI_ID FLI_CO FLI_AIRCRA DEPT_AIRPORT ARRV_AIRPORT DEPT_TIME                      ARRV_TIME               FLI_PRICE

     1 BD425  Boeing 707            1           12 18-MAR-12 02.24.00 AM          18-MAR-12 06.24.00 AM         520
     2 LX345  Beriev 30             6            7 20-MAR-12 03.30.00 PM          20-MAR-12 04.20.00 PM         250
     3 NZ4445 Boeing 720            9           14 25-MAR-12 09.00.00 AM          25-MAR-12 05.00.00 PM         290
     4 TP351  Boeing 767           10           15 25-MAR-12 11.25.00 AM          25-MAR-12 03.35.00 PM         399
     5 BA472  Boeing 720            5           14 26-MAR-12 01.05.00 PM          26-MAR-12 04.15.00 PM         365
```

**Accommodation**

```
ACC_ID ACC_TYPE_CODE ACC_DESC                                           ACC_PRICEPN  ACC_ROOMS  RESORT_ID ACC_ADDR                          CITY_ID

     1             1 Three bedroom bungalow near theme park                     500          3          1
     2             1 Two bedroom bungalow next to disney house                  350          2          1
     3             1 One bedroom bungalow with lake view                        250          2          2
     4             2 One bedroom chalet near the lake                           150          1          2
     5             2 Four bedroom chalet near the tree house                    600          4          3
```

**Reservation**

```
RESV_ID     EMP_ID BOOKING_CUS_ID RESV_DATE HOLIDAY_S HOLIDAY_E IN_FLIGHT_ID OUT_FLIGHT_ID IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO     ACC_ID   SUBTOTAL

     1        338              1 16-FEB-12 18-MAR-12 20-APR-12            1            11                  2                   2          2
     2        335              3 10-JAN-12 20-MAR-12 22-APR-12            2            12                  2                   2          4
     3        338              5 05-MAR-12 25-MAR-12 26-APR-12            3            13                  2                   2          6
     4        328              7 02-JAN-12 25-MAR-12 25-APR-12            4            14                  2                   2          7
     5        311              9 20-JAN-12 26-MAR-12 21-APR-12            5            15                  2                   2
     6        317             11 07-JAN-12 27-MAR-12 22-APR-12            6            16                  2                   2
     7        344             13 29-FEB-12 15-MAR-12 12-APR-12            7            17                  2                   2
     8        326             15 11-JAN-12 18-MAR-12 12-APR-14            8            18                  2                   2
     9        329             17 16-JAN-12 19-MAR-12 17-APR-12                                                                   25
    10        323             19 18-FEB-12 20-MAR-12 21-APR-12                                                                   19
```

**Okay I managed to yield the results that i wanted**

```
SELECT HR.RESV_ID, F_IN.FLI_ID, F_IN.FLI_PRICE, F_OUT.FLI_ID, F_OUT.FLI_PRICE, AC.ACC_ID, AC.ACC_PRICEPN, NVL(F_IN.FLI_PRICE,0)+NVL(F_OUT.FLI_PRICE,0)+NVL(AC.ACC_PRICEPN,0) AS TOTAL
FROM HOLIDAY_RESERVATION HR 
LEFT JOIN FLIGHT F_IN ON HR.IN_FLIGHT_ID = F_IN.FLI_ID
LEFT JOIN FLIGHT F_OUT ON HR.OUT_FLIGHT_ID = F_OUT.FLI_ID
LEFT JOIN ACCOMMODATION AC ON HR.ACC_ID = AC.ACC_ID
ORDER BY HR.RESV_ID;
```

**YIELDS**

```
   RESV_ID     FLI_ID  FLI_PRICE     FLI_ID  FLI_PRICE     ACC_ID ACC_PRICEPN      TOTAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ----------
         1          1        500         11        555          2         350       1405
         2          2        150         12        253          4         150        553
         3          3        300         13        345          6         450       1095
         4          4        450         14        343          7         650       1443
         5          5        345         15        242                               587
         6          6        460         16        460                               920
         7          7        250         17        250                               500
         8          8        550         18        550                              1100
         9                                                     25         250        250
        10                                                     19         450        450
```

**And the following statement is to update the reservation table.**
*Thanks to Leigh Riffel from DBA stackxchange for the following code*

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R SET SUBTOTAL = 
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT F.FLI_PRICE FROM FLIGHT F WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID), 0) +
   NVL((SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN FROM ACCOMMODATION AC WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID), 0);
```

**Now the subtotal is populated with the values obtained from the sum performed above** >>

```
 RESV_ID     EMP_ID BOOKING_CUS_ID RESV_DATE HOLIDAY_S HOLIDAY_E IN_FLIGHT_ID OUT_FLIGHT_ID IN_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO OUT_FLIGHT_SEATS_NO     ACC_ID   SUBTOTAL
---------- ---------- -------------- --------- --------- --------- ------------ ------------- ------------------ ------------------- ---------- ----------
         1        338              1 16-FEB-12 18-MAR-12 20-APR-12            1            11                  2                   2          2       1405
         2        335              3 10-JAN-12 20-MAR-12 22-APR-12            2            12                  2                   2          4        553
         3        338              5 05-MAR-12 25-MAR-12 26-APR-12            3            13                  2                   2          6       1095
         4        328              7 02-JAN-12 25-MAR-12 25-APR-12            4            14                  2                   2          7       1443
         5        311              9 20-JAN-12 26-MAR-12 21-APR-12            5            15                  2                   2                   587
         6        317             11 07-JAN-12 27-MAR-12 22-APR-12            6            16                  2                   2                   920
         7        344             13 29-FEB-12 15-MAR-12 12-APR-12            7            17                  2                   2                   500
         8        326             15 11-JAN-12 18-MAR-12 12-APR-14            8            18                  2                   2                  1100
         9        329             17 16-JAN-12 19-MAR-12 17-APR-12                                                                   25        250
        10        323             19 18-FEB-12 20-MAR-12 21-APR-12                                                                   19        450
```

**Subsequently the code was added to a trigger (which was the original intention)**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER HR_SUBTOTAL
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON HOLIDAY_RESERVATION
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      NVL((SELECT F.Fli_Price FROM Flight F WHERE F.Fli_ID = :new.In_Flight_ID), 0) +
      NVL((SELECT F.Fli_Price FROM Flight F WHERE F.Fli_ID = :new.Out_Flight_ID), 0) +
      NVL((SELECT AC.Acc_PricePn FROM Accomodation AC WHERE AC.Acc_ID = :new.Acc_ID), 0)
      INTO :new.Subtotal
   FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `SUM`, assuming you want to treat `NULL` values as 0, you'd just need to do an `NVL` on the numbers

```
NVL( DEPART_FLIGHT_PRICE, 0 ) +
NVL( RETURN_FLIGHT_PRICE, 0 ) +
NVL( ACCOMMODATION_PRICE, 0 )
```

As for the `UPDATE`, it sounds like you just need a correlated `UPDATE` statement.

```
UPDATE reservation r
   SET subtotal = (SELECT (SELECT NVL( DEPART_FLIGHT_PRICE, 0 ) +
                          NVL( RETURN_FLIGHT_PRICE, 0 ) +
                          NVL( ACCOMMODATION_PRICE, 0 )
                     FROM (SELECT RESV_ID, 
                                  BOOKING_CUS_ID, 
                                  ACC_ID,
                                  (SELECT F.FLI_PRICE 
                                     FROM FLIGHT F 
                                    WHERE F.FLI_ID = R.IN_FLIGHT_ID) AS DEPART_FLIGHT_PRICE, 
                                  (SELECT F1.FLI_PRICE 
                                     FROM FLIGHT F1 
                                    WHERE F1.FLI_ID = R.OUT_FLIGHT_ID) AS RETURN_FLIGHT_PRICE, 
                                  (SELECT AC.ACC_PRICEPN 
                                     FROM ACCOMMODATION AC 
                                    WHERE AC.ACC_ID = R.ACC_ID) AS ACCOMMODATION_PRICE
                             FROM dual));
```

Comment: Hi, I was just reading an article on NVL, Ill try it tomorrow its 4:00 AM :) thanks Justin

Comment: Seems over-complicated. Wouldn't Oracle let you do that just like this: `… SET subtotal = NVL( (the FLIGHT F subquery), 0) + NVL( (the FLIGHT F1 subquery), 0) + NVL( (the ACCOMMODATION AC subquery), 0)`?

Comment: Hey I've tried to make it work for so many hours but still get errors, the flight prices and accommodation prices will not have nulls, however the acc_id may not be referenced in reservation if a customer has not made a reservation for a accommodation same for flight. so the primary key for acc_id may not be present in reservation, this is where the null is, to make it clearer, we have to check whether the reservation was for accommodation or flight only or both, then add the prices for those things

Answer (score 1):

You are asking:

> How do I sum up the price fields, as you can see some of them can have nulls.
>
> ```
> DEPART_FLIGHT_PRICE RETURN_FLIGHT_PRICE ACCOMMODATION_PRICE
> ```

Just enclose them in NVL function as follows:

```
NVL(DEPART_FLIGHT_PRICE, 0)
```

and then sum them up.

For the second part, what you need is a MERGE statement. A good example is at http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=203

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, however in the reservation table the prices are null because the reservation was not made for that type of booking. however in their parent tables, the prices will always have a value and this is the problem that i am having, because the query that i am writing only shows those reservations which have both vales from flight and accommodation and is not showing reservations for only accommodation or only flight. ta